# Why this code does appending only in the trace-log and not others. How do I correct this?

Tags: xml, log4j, log4j2

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
<Properties>
        <Property name="log-path">logs</Property>
    </Properties>
  <Appenders>
   <Console name="console-log" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
  <File name="trace-log" fileName="${log-path}/trace.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
<File name="error-log" fileName="${log-path}/error.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
<File name="debug-log" fileName="${log-path}/debug.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
<File name="info-log" fileName="${log-path}/info.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>

    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="error-log"/>
<AppenderRef ref="console-log"/>
    </Root>
<Root level="info">
      <appender-ref ref="info-log"/>
<AppenderRef ref="console-log"/>
    </Root>
<Root level="debug">
      <AppenderRef ref="debug-log"/>
<AppenderRef ref="console-log"/>
    </Root>
<Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="trace-log"/>
<AppenderRef ref="console-log"/>
    </Root>

  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

My code written above appends everything only to the trace-log. In fact root that is called last is only getting all log information stored. How do I correct this? I want all log files to be working as intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

You have a few problems here:

1. You can only have a single root logger. You have several. Log4j is only going to use one of them.
2. It appears you want only a specific level to go to each file. The level attribute says "Let events of this level OR GREATER" be logged. So a root logger with level="error" will allow events at level error or fatal. A root logger at info will allow events at level info, error or fatal.

You can try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
  <Properties>
    <Property name="log-path">logs</Property>
  </Properties>
  <Appenders>
    <Console name="console-log" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <PatternLayout pattern="[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>
    <File name="trace-log" fileName="${log-path}/trace.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
        <ThresholdFilter level="debug" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>
    <File name="error-log" fileName="${log-path}/error.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
        <Filters>
          <ThresholdFilter level="error" onMatch="NEUTRAL" onMismatch="DENY"/>
          <ThresholdFilter level="fatal" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
        </Filters>
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>
    <File name="debug-log" fileName="${log-path}/debug.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
        <Filters>
          <ThresholdFilter level="debug" onMatch="NEUTRAL" onMismatch="DENY"/>
          <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
        </Filters>            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>
    <File name="info-log" fileName="${log-path}/info.log" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
        <Filters>
          <ThresholdFilter level="info" onMatch="NEUTRAL" onMismatch="DENY"/>
          <ThresholdFilter level="warn" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="ACCEPT"/>
        </Filters>
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace">
      <AppenderRef ref="error-log"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="info-log"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="debug-log"/>
      <AppenderRef ref="trace-log/>
      <AppenderRef ref="console-log"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Nice detailed example!